Why is Dirac Delta Function term in QFT's momentum operator not infinite?
In Weigand's Quantum Field Theory notes, he has the following equations for the spatial components of the momentum operator.
$$
\begin{align}
P^i &= \int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3} \dot{\phi(\vec{x})}\partial_i \phi(\vec{x})\\
 &= \int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}p^ia^{\dagger}(\vec{p})a(\vec{p}) + \Delta_{p^i}\tag{1.80}
\end{align} 
$$
With equation 1.81, $$\Delta_{p^i} = \int d^3p p^i \delta^{(3)}(0)  \equiv 0.\tag{1.81}$$
Can someone explain to me why $\Delta_{p^i} \equiv 0$?

You re-define the ordering of the operators; i.e., you ignore the term. It is not $0$, it is undefined.

$\delta^3(0)$ is a divergent (i.e cutoff-dependent)  number, but it is a constant, and can be taken ouside the integral. Then  $\int d^3p p^i$ is zero by symmetry.   As a consequence,  the spatial components of the momentum of the vacuum are zero.  You are right to worry though, the energy of the vacuum is genuiunely divergent.

Thanks @mikestone . That makes sense.

If it makes you feel more comfortable, the undefined integral $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty dp , p$ will vanish in any "reasonable" (i.e. symmetric) UV regularization like $\int\limits_{-\Lambda}^{+\Lambda} dp , p=0$. As this does not work for $P^0$, you have to "renormalize" the divergent contribution from the zero point energy anyway. This can be done by "normal ordering" $a a^\dagger \to a^\dagger a$ solving your problem with $\vec{P}$ simultaneously.
